# Radio button validation is not working jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

Hi i am working on a MVC application and have a model in which i have done with validations by making Required attribute on properties.

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
 public string Name { get; set; }

 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gender is required.")]
 public string Gender{ get; set; }
```

I have a button click and in jquery on this button click i have done.

```
$("#frmInfo").validate();
```

The problem is validation is showing for Name which is bind to text box but not for Gender which is bind to radio button.Below is the html rendered in browser.

```
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Name is required." id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" aria-required="true" class="input-validation-error" aria-describedby="Name-error" aria-invalid="true">
    <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    <span id="Name-error" class="">Name is required.</span>

    <input id="Gender0" name="Gender" type="radio" value="Male" title="Male">
    <label for="Male">Male</label>
    <input id="Gender1" name="Gender" type="radio" value="Female" title="Female">
    <label for="Female">Female</label>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Gender" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

I am not sure what is missing here that radio button validation is not working.

Comment: If you're using the Unobtrusive Validation plugin, then you cannot call `.validate()`.  It's constructed and called automatically by Unobtrusive and yours will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this below steps and I hope it resolve your problem.

**HTML**

Create one hidden control to hold the radio button values. The default value for this hidden control is empty.

```
<input id="hdnGender" name="hdnGender" type="hidden" value=""/>
```

**JQuery**

Store the radio button selected values into hidden control.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input[name='Gender']").on("click", function () {
        $("#hdnGender").val($(this).val());
}
```

**MVC**

Validate the hidden control value through any back end script.

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gender is required.")]
 public string Gender{ get; set; }
```